# Could not connect to the in-process QML profiler

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, profiler

Created default `Profile` build configuration for my application and trying to run it in QML Profile, however [**Enable Profiling** button](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html#using-qml-profiler) does not work and after some period of time  I got the following error:

```
Could not connect to the in-process QML profiler within 128 s.
Do you want to retry and wait 256 s?
```

[image: QML Profiler error]

All necessary options in **Project** Build settings are enabled:

[image: Project settings]

[`QQmlDebuggingEnabler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18151226/630169) suggestion does not work. Performance analyzer was setup correctly and works fine. How to make QML Profiler to work as well?

Comment: Did you solve? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Mark seems solved in recent QtC versions, not facing any more.