# QT 5 - Debugging C++ and QML

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qml

I am trying to debug a QML/C++ application and have both active.

If I set both C++ and QML debugging in `Projects > Run > Debugger Settings` and enable QML Debugging and Profiling in `Projects > Build` only C++ breakpoints work; QML debugging does not work.

Checking the processes at this point - the QtCreator process and the debuggee - I can see that the process being debugged does not open the debugging port for the QML Debugger and QtCreator tries (and failt) to connect to that port.

If I deselect C++ Debugging - QML debugging works fine and (obviously) C++ does not.

Is there any way to have both active? Or what can I set\check\enable to get more info.

Qt 5.12.4 with CMake
VC++2017 Generator
Windows10 x86

Comment: you should enable both `Enable C++` and `Enable QML` in `Project/Build & Run/Run/Debugger settings` to (obviously) enable debugging of both C++ and QML. CMake requires some additional steps, more info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-qml.html)

Comment: I have had to instantiate a `QQmlDebuggingEnabler` also (with CMake project)

Comment: @folibis - I enabled both `C++` and `QML` debugging without any success; still trying to understand why.

Comment: @Amfasis - will try that; did not now about QQmlDebuggingEnabler.

Comment: Tried suggestions from @Amfasis and from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366495/how-to-qt-qml-debugging-and-or-profiling) with no success. `QQmlDebuggingEnabler ` throws an `undefined error` **maybe I am missing something** and adding a define for `QT_QML_DEBUG` gives a warning that it's already defined.